# parse a list of string using java.util.stream api + JAVA8

Tags: java, collections, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I want to use the below code using new java8 APIs like (stream, lambda, predicates) and reduce it to minimum number of lines

```
public static List<Long> validateChannelList(String channelList) {
    List<Long> channelListNumber = new ArrayList<Long>();
            String[] channels = channelList.split(",");
    for (String channel : channels) {
                    channelListNumber.add(Long.parseLong(channel));
                }
    }
```

please help to reduce the foreach loop or the whole method into minimum number of lines usinf JAVA8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using static import of `toList` and assuming you don't specifically need an `ArrayList`:

```
Pattern.compile(",").splitAsStream(channelList)
  .map(Long::parseLong)
  .collect(toList());
```

Comment: Better use `Long::valueOf` because it already returns a `Long` and it hasn't to be autoboxed.

Comment: Could you elaborate more about the static toList() method, I didn't get that part of code.

Comment: It's customary to use `import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList`.  Otherwise you can do `Collectors.toList()` instead of `toList()`

Comment: @Flown, from performance point of view there's absolutely no difference. `Long.valueOf` just makes the same explicit boxing inside.

Comment: By the way for empty string OP's code will throw `NumberFormatException` while answer code will return an empty List in Java-8. Though in Java-9 it will also throw `NumberFormatException`! See [JDK-8069325](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8069325) for details.

Comment: @TagirValeev It's not about performance it's about clean code. You should use `Long::parseLong` to get `long` and `Long::valueOf` to get `Long`.

Comment: @TagirValeev that's a good catch, thank you.  OP can use `Arrays.stream(channelList.split(","))` if other behavior is desired.